# from a stream "FramedRead" how to "do something" in every chunk

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I would like to display the upload progress of a file using the crate [indicatif](https://crates.io/crates/indicatif), I am uploading the file asynchronous using [reqwest](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.7/reqwest/struct.Body.html#method.wrap_stream) with something like this:

```
use tokio::fs::File;
use tokio_util::codec::{BytesCodec, FramedRead};

let file = File::open(file_path).await?;
let stream = FramedRead::new(file, BytesCodec::new());
let body = Body::wrap_stream(stream);
client.put(url).body(body)
```

The progress bar is implemented like this:

```
use indicatif::ProgressBar;

let bar = ProgressBar::new(1000);
for _ in 0..1000 {
    bar.inc(1);
    // ...
}
bar.finish();
```

How from the `stream`:

```
let stream = FramedRead::new(file, BytesCodec::new());
// how on every chunk do X ? 
let body = Body::wrap_stream(stream);
```

could I call `bar.inc(1)` on every interaction?

From the docs I see that there is a [read_buffer](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/tokio_util/codec/struct.FramedRead.html#method.read_buffer) but how to iterate over it in a way that I could use it for calling a custom function or also count the bytes send in the cased I could display "bytes sent" so far for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TryStreamExt::inspect_ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.inspect_ok), for instance, which will call a closure with a reference to every `Ok(item)` in the stream when that item is consumed.

```rust
use futures::stream::TryStreamExt;
use tokio_util::codec::{BytesCodec, FramedRead};

let stream = FramedRead::new(file, BytesCodec::new())
    .inspect_ok(|chunk| {
        // do X with chunk...
    });

let body = Body::wrap_stream(stream);
```